# Ruby sort by block without converting to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My database has a column that includes a customer's first and last name in the same field.  (It comes in formatted that way from an API.)

To sort by the customer's last name, I need to split the string.

```
schedule_projects.sort_by{|x| x.sold_to_name.split(" ").last}
```

However, with all of the other sorting that we do in this app, we use the order method and then call .page

But the sort_by method returns an array instead of an ActiveRecord relation.  And you can't call .page on an array.

For a temporary solution, we're just calling .order on the sold_to_name.  But we'd really like to be able to sort these by the customer's last name.  Is there any way to sort by a block without converting the output to an array?

Comment: Why don't use separate columns?

Comment: Minor note, if you need to split on `" "` and only need the _last_ result: `x.sold_to_name.rpartition(" ").last`

Comment: The 1,000 pound pink elephant in the room is that this won't give the correct results for any last name that has spaces in it like Von Trapp or De Val. At best it's a very naive solution and at worst it will actually offend your users. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: How do you want to sort names like "Jean-Claude van Damme"?

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has split_part function. First argument is the text, second argument the delimiter character, and third argument is the position in this case the last one.

```
schedule_projects.order(Arel.sql("split_part(sold_to_name, ' ', -1)"))
```

Comment: For me, this syntax produced the error: "G::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR:  field position must be greater than zero".

Comment: Looking up the error, I learned that we are not allowed to use a -1 index in this case. Instead, we must reverse the string, get the first part, then reverse again.

schedule_projects.order(Arel.sql("reverse(split_part(reverse(sold_to_name), ' ', 1))"))

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by a block without loading the records isn't actually possible. In order to process the records in Ruby you need to actually get the data into your application.

A naive solution is to use database functions like SUBSTRING or SPLIT_PART in the order clause to break the string into parts. It will work great until it actually encounters reality and you have to deal with:

- Names with prefixes or suffixes.
- Multiple surnames.
- Cultures that don't use the forename surname convention.
- People that only have one name.
- ...

The very idea of programatically splitting a full name into it's constituent parts is unfortunately broken and you won't actually be able to implement this properly without good input data.